# viewing gridView items in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I create a class for a gridview it works correctly and I test it in other parts of app it is working correctly. the Custom layout only contains an imageView in those parts which I test. for an activity I need to use both imageView and textView together and here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/khattesevom" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:background="@drawable/textblockbio"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Class's Code:

```
public class GridLyrics extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private final String[] title;
private final int image[];
public GridLyrics(Context context, String[] t, int[] img)
{
    mContext = context;
    this.title = t;
    this.image = img;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return title.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    if (convertView == null)
    {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_lyrics, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        textView.setText(title[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(image[position]);
    }
    else
    {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}
}
```

and here is the way I use it :

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView) tb2.findViewById(R.id.gridView4);
    String[] t = {"Marham", "Onam Mesle Mane", "Mikham", "Door", "To Besh Migi Mariz", "Oraman", "Test"};
    int[] img = {R.drawable.ic_khattesevom, R.drawable.ic_khattesevom, R.drawable.ic_khattesevom, R.drawable.ic_khattesevom, R.drawable.ic_khattesevom, R.drawable.ic_khattesevom, R.drawable.ic_khattesevom};
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridLyrics(getContext(), t, img));
```

My problem is in the last row the textView dosn't appear! it shows the picture but not the textView.

[the picture of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcApi.png)
I don't know what I can do!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

set `TextView` height to **`match parent`** 
and remove padding.
change your xml like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/khattesevom" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:background="@drawable/textblockbio"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. Change your `LinearLayout` to `ScrollView` that way by scrolling down you would be able to get his name

Comment: Why? Pls explain a little. Thanks.

Comment: 1st the size of it, it just shows one row but you can scroll to see others, 2nd after you reach the bottom the item's position changes and some of them disapears!